# jCarouselLite turning buttons on/off

Tags: javascript, jcarousellite

I have a very simple jcarousellite script working, but I want to be able to turn 'off' the left or right button when there aren't any more items to be displayed either right or left. Easiest way would be to simply change the background image used for the prev/next buttons I'm using via the div.

http://sagescience.com/dev/car_test/

I'm brand new to this, any gurus willing to lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

circular: false,

Comment: I took a look at your example above, but it is still a circular example. I am looking for the same solution; I'd like the left or right buttons to disappear only when the slideshow is at either end of the items it can present. Of course, mid-show both would be present. How did you achieve that if you did?

Comment: @Angelina: When you're at one end of a non-circular carousel, the class-name 'disabled' is added to the appropriate button.